# Get image of div using html2canvas not working with previous version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make image of `div` using `html2canvas` but my code is not working well.  **Just install the new version of html2canvas and this is working fine**
See whats the problem with previous version here is code

```js
html2canvas($("#canvas-preview"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    theCanvas = canvas;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Convert and download as image 
    //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
    $("#img-out").append(canvas);
    // Clean up 
    //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

```css
#canvas-preview {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red
}
#canvas-preview::before,
#image-container::before {
  background-color: green;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#custom-canvas {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Anton';
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas-preview" class="">
  <div id="custom-canvas">
    <div>
      <span line-num="1" class="text-lines" style="font-size: 76.7025px;">ARFAN</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span line-num="2" class="text-lines" style="font-size: 67.7685px;">HAIDER</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="image-out"></div>
```

This function get the image but not same as `div` it get only half a image not full. what the problem is with this code. ?

**UPDATE**

Output look like this image.

[image]

Comment: do you mean you only get the bit that's green, i.e. the actual div content, and the canvas isn't getting the "overflow"? because that would've been useful information

Comment: try `display:inline-block;width:auto;` for `#canvas-preview{` style (replacing width, adding display to what you have)

Comment: Your problem is certainly caused by your `:before` pseudo-elements. Old versions of html2canvas didn't supported it. Try with the [latest one](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks this is working fine in new htmml2canvas version

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working for me

```js
html2canvas($("#canvas-preview"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    theCanvas = canvas;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Convert and download as image 
    //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
    $("#img-out").append(canvas);
    // Clean up 
    //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

```css
#canvas-preview{
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
#canvas-preview::before, #image-container::before{
    background-color: green;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
#custom-canvas{
    margin:10px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:2;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Anton';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-preview" class="">
    <div id="custom-canvas">
        <div>
            <span line-num="1" class="text-lines" style="font-size: 76.7025px;">ARFAN</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span line-num="2" class="text-lines" style="font-size: 67.7685px;">HAIDER</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div id="image-out"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't want to set `width:auto` it must be `200px` why this is not working when the `width:200px`

Comment: please see the updation it look like this without `width:auto`